# Onmouseover does not work with Django - Python

Tags: python, html, django

I copied html to django, like everything was set up, there are pictures, etc. But here with onmouseover the problem - does not work.
Tried it -
`onmouseover="this.src={% static 'res/ico/instagram_h.png'%}"`

```
onmouseover="this.src="{% static 'res/ico/instagram_h.png'%}"
onmouseover= "{% static 'res/ico/instagram_h.png'%}"
```

And many more options, but the picture does not change, although if you just upload the html file to the browser, it all works.

Comment: look at the redered HTML and you will see the problem.

Comment: <a href="#"><img src="/static/res/ico/instagram.png" onmouseover="this.src=/static/res/ico/instagram_h.png" onmouseout="this.src='/static/res/ico/instagram.png" alt=""></a>

Comment: But I do not see a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments on your question, it seems to be a quoting issue.

Try this:

```
onmouseover="this.src='{% static 'res/ico/instagram_h.png' %}'"
```

Comment: Oh my God, WORKS! Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help :)